# Create auto-updating rows based on the time in mysql

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

I am building some game logic in mysql and ran into a conundrum. Player has technologies that he/she can upgrade by purchasing it. Then after a set interval of time, the player's level will increase. This way the level is updated in real time and not when the player does something as if ran from a trigger. How can mysql update the player's level based on whether the upgrade process is complete and in realtime update?

My first thoughts:
Run a mysql event every second or every minute to check for expired technologies and upgrade them appropriately. After starting to build with this idea, I quickly saw my overhead increasing. Unless I use some beefy hardware, I don't think I could run 4 or 5 or these processes on one server and effectively run my game server.

My new idea:
I was playing with views and came up with an interesting work around to my problem that sorts this out a lot more resource friendly.

First I have my players_technologies table:

```
CREATE TABLE `players_technologies` (
  `playertech_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tech_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `next_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`playertech_id`),
  KEY `fk_players_technologies_1_idx` (`player_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_players_technologies_1` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`player_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is where the player's technology level is stored. The `tech_id` is simply a reference to the technologies details like name and shouldn't have much effect on this setup.

Then I created a `VIEW` for the technologies to be accessed from elsewhere in the database.

```
CREATE VIEW `players_technologies_real` AS 
   SELECT `players_technologies`.`playertech_id` AS `playertech_id`,
      `players_technologies`.`player_id` AS `player_id`,
      `players_technologies`.`tech_id` AS `tech_id`,
      `players_technologies`.`next_update` AS `next_update`,
      `players_technologies`.`level` AS `level`,
      if( isnull(`players_technologies`.`next_update`),
         `players_technologies`.`level`,
         if((`players_technologies`.`next_update` < now()),
            (`players_technologies`.`level` + 1),
            `players_technologies`.`level`)) AS `real_level` 
  FROM `players_technologies`;
```

This checks the expiration date, `next_update`, to see if that time has past. If it has it will display the `real_level` as incremented by 1. This is the field the rest of the database should use for logic and stay in realtime.

Then I can add a `TRIGGER` before an update on a row in players_technologies that is will reject an update of `next_update` if the expiration date in not past. If it is past, it will increment the level and proceed with the `UPDATE`. This `TRIGGER` looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `players_technologies_BU` BEFORE UPDATE ON `players_technologies` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF(NEW.`next_update` <> OLD.`next_update`) THEN
        IF(OLD.`next_update` > NOW()) THEN
            SET msg = CONCAT('Player Technology Error: Player Tech #',NEW.`playertech_id`,' is not finished with it current research.');
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
        ELSE 
            SET NEW.`level` = OLD.`level` + 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Can anyone see how this is improperly setup? Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: It will work, however views tend to be really slow in mysql (has to do with the optimizer, nothing you can do about it unless you strt hacking mysql) (at least before version 5.7), so either upgrade to mariadb which seems to have less of this problem, or do not use views.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen - Would it better to wrap the logic that is the view into a function and use the function to determine the level. i.e. players_tech_real(`next_update`,`level`) AS `real_level`. This would skip the need for a view then.

Comment: You could do that. Then you can apply any where criteria by altering your query in the function, and you would still have only one place to maintain your code. The optimizer does not have problems with that part.

Comment: Thank you. My goal with the `VIEW` was to make the calculation portable. The `FUNCTION` effectively does the same thing.

Comment: Test MariaDB if possible: They are actively paying attention to the view issues. It also might solve your issue without too much effort.

Comment: Right now, a function works beautifully for what I need. I will look into MariaDB a little later. I have too many new things to look at now.

Answer (score 0):

After Norbert's comments I have chosen to drop the `VIEW` as it is not optimum. I have decided to write a user defined function in mysql to accomplish what I am trying to do. First here is the `FUNCTION` I have tested.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `get_playertech_real`(next_update DATETIME, my_level INT) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE real_level INT;
    IF isnull(next_update) THEN
        SET real_level = my_level;
    ELSE
        IF next_update < now() THEN
            SET real_level = my_level + 1;
        ELSE 
            SET real_level = my_level;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN real_level;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This function could be a little cleaner but works properly. Then you can access the "real" tech level by calling the `FUNCTION` like so:

```
SELECT `playertech_id` AS `playertech_id`,
    `player_id` AS `player_id`,
    `tech_id` AS `tech_id`,
    `next_update` AS `next_update`,
    `level` AS `level`,
    get_playertech_real(`next_update`,`level`) AS `real_level`
FROM `players_technologies`
```

This is tested and works. But this is not test on very large data sets yet.